# Waiting forever for local host after saving to database

Tags: node.js, node-mssql

When i want to save to database on submit chrom giveing me massage waiting for localhost and it is forever. how i can fix this issue. The data are saved and everything seems ok where is a problem... please help...`enter code here`

```
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
        const mysql = require('mysql');
        var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});


        var connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host:'127.0.0.1',
            user:'root',
            password: '',
            database: 'sm_db'

        });
        connection.connect(function(err){
            if(!err){
                console.log('CONNECTED');
            } else{
                console.log('ERROR');
            }
        });

        app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
            const germant = req.body.germant;
            const germantMsqlData = {germant};
        connection.query('INSERT INTO summersidedatatable SET ?', germantMsqlData, function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
            res.send('SEND GERMANT DATA ERROR');
            }

          });
        });

    };
```

Comment: is data inserting to database?

Comment: yes data is inserted to database

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you dont send a response if there is no error:

```
        app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
            const germant = req.body.germant;
            const germantMsqlData = {germant};
        connection.query('INSERT INTO summersidedatatable SET ?', germantMsqlData, function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
            res.send('SEND GERMANT DATA ERROR');
            }
             //here you are missing something
             res.send('Done with query');
          });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```js
 const germantMsqlData = {germant};
```

With the below code. Please provide your database field name

```js
  const germantMsqlData={
      "data_base_field_name":germant
         }
```

Here you have mentioned the error part success part you have not mentioned.
 res.send();

**TRY MY CODE**

```js
app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
            const germant = req.body.germant;
            const germantMsqlData={
          "data_base_field_name":germant
            }
        connection.query('INSERT INTO summersidedatatable SET ?', germantMsqlData, function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
            res.send('SEND GERMANT DATA ERROR');
            }

             res.send('Redirect');
          });
        });
```

replace data_base_field_name to your field name

Answer (score 0):

You missing finish the request,  then you browser will wait forever

```
        app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
            const germant = req.body.germant;
            const germantMsqlData = {germant};
        connection.query('INSERT INTO summersidedatatable SET ?', germantMsqlData, function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
                return res.send('SEND GERMANT DATA ERROR'); // finish the request in error case 
            }
            res.end(); // finish the request in success case, just end the request, does not send any data back to client.

          });
        });
```

Comment: res.end send me to blank page how to just insert data to db and after do stay at the same page like sending never happend

Comment: @MichałMi Do you want reload page after insert the data?

Comment: i know i can rerender the page res.render('index'); but i just want to cloce connection and do nothing on client side

Comment: @MichałMi maybe what you need is a request ajax from client side